# How to securely store decryptable passwords

Tags: encryption, passwords, hash

I'll quickly outline the purpose of our application:

The user logs in using his username and password. He will receive a list of servers he can connect to. After choosing a server the connection to this server is established.

Some more details about the application that complicate our requirements:

- One user can have multiple devices
- Server lists can be shared amongst multiple users

**What's the best way to store the server passwords on our application server?**

Ideas that we already played with:

- Symmetic encryption using the user's password as key

  - Won't work with shared list
  - Would need to store the user's password on the client if don't want him to log in every time he's using the application
- Symmetic encryption using the user's password hash (bcrypt) as key

  - Won't work with shared list
  - If an attacker has access to the server he will be able to decrypt the server passwords using the user's password hash, that is also stored in the database
- Using bcrypt to securely store the passwords

  - Won't work as we will need the plain password to connect
- Storing the passwords in plain text

  - C'mon...

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: Please don't store decryptable passwords.

Comment: Have you seen Apache Guacamole? It does all this already.

Comment: Why couple the credentials to the server with the app user's password? Why can't the app manage the credentials separately? You say that the server lists can be shared, but then suggest that the credentials are also shared. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Can you clarify who enters the server passwords? The users? Also are the remote servers you connect to under your control? If not, if there are any methods other than username+password to connect to them? I'm not quite sure I understand the use case of multiple users sharing passwords to remote servers they add, though.

Comment: @user it's not always *quite* that straight-forward.  You certainly shouldn't store *user-provided* passwords in de-cryptable formats, but that is simply because of the risk of password re-use, and a desire to protect the user from themselves.  System generated passwords are a bit more flexible, since you can have high confidence that the user didn't also use it for their email/banking login.  In this case the OP may be referring to system-generated passwords and so relaxing that requirement is reasonable.  Moreover since they are for use with a third party, the plain text is required.

Comment: @schroeder I don't want to get too deep into the application because it's not necessary to understand the challenge: The user shouldn't need to enter the server credentials on all of his devices, hence the synchronisation. Sharing of team-server credentials might not be necessary, as every user has its own credentials, but sometimes we have such a thing as a service user and it would be nice if these credentials can be shared.

Comment: @jcaron Server-passwords are entered by the user, yes. And no, servers are not under our control. See my previous comment onto why shared passwords. It's not the main use case, though.

Answer (score 1):

> Symmetic encryption using the user's password as key

This is the base of a correct solution. If you want to store it securely, you need to encrypt it with a key you don't have. So that leaves the user's password.

To solve the problems, you just need more layers of indirection.

Shared lists are encrypted with a single key, and that key is in turn encrypted with the key of each user that has access to it. That way, multiple users can decrypt the decryption key and access the list.

To avoid logging in each time, use an additional key that the user decrypts with his password. You hold on to this key, so that reauthentication isn't required, without storing the password.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Can you clarify a bit on the last part: As I understand this sounds like some sort of a token to keep the login alive (e.g. JSON Web Token). Do we encrypt the server passwords with this key? Then both information would be on server side... I think I misunderstood something here :)